# How to improve union query?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, union

I have a query which is 'working' but slow and feels very poor and I don't want to have to update each time we add/remove a supplier!

Basically I have a table of 'prices' and for each suppler I need to get their price for the code based on their longest code match (this is working), I repeat this for each `supplier_id` and then union them together finally joining the supplier names to the results

Item code ABC123456

```
select t1.*, s.name from
(
(Select * from prices where ABC123456 like CONCAT(code_prefix , '%') AND supplier_id = 1
ORDER BY LENGTH(code_prefix) Desc Limit 1)

UNION

(Select * from prices where ABC123456 like CONCAT(code_prefix , '%') AND supplier_id = 2
ORDER BY LENGTH(code_prefix) Desc Limit 1)

UNION

(Select * from prices where ABC123456 like CONCAT(code_prefix , '%') AND supplier_id = 3
ORDER BY LENGTH(code_prefix) Desc Limit 1)

... for each supplier

) t1

join supplier s on t1.supplier_id = s.id
order by buy_price asc
```

1. How can I run this automatically for any number of suppliers (ie run for each supplier in supplier table and then join the best result from each) - I cannot get my head round it
2. Performance is not great, 300 ms for each query and I have 400000 codes (in codes table) too run through. Should I be doing this as a stored procedure? would that make a big difference although it should only be run when we get a pricing update 1 or 2 times a month per supplier!
3. Is it possible to the populate a new table price_order (code, sequence) where code is from above and then sequence is the supplier_id's in price order (low to high), I can do this is an app, but is there a smarter way to do in DB for better performance?

Currently running 10.0.27-MariaDB but can possibly change if really needed!

Thanks in advance

Update requirements

prices table (other columns exist too!)

```
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| code_prefix   | suppler_id   | price.    |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| ABC123        | 1            | 100       |
| ABC1          | 1            | 123       |
| ABC177        | 1            | 723       |
| ABC12         | 2            | 111       |
| ABC           | 2            | 222       |
| ABC111        | 3            | 001       |
| AB            | 3            | 234       |
| A             | 4            | 010       |
| B             | 4            | 710       |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

We have another table of codes which we need to lookup against the prefix in the prices table

```
+---------------+
| code          |
+---------------+
| ABC123456     |
| ABC155555     |
| ABC12         |
| ABC7777777    |
+---------------+
```

So for each row in the code table I need the best/longest match for each supplier

```
so code ABC123456 will return
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| code_prefix   | suppler_id   | price     |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| ABC123        | 1            | 100       |
| ABC12         | 2            | 111       |
| AB            | 3            | 234       |
| A             | 4            | 010       |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+


code ABC155555 will return
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| code_prefix   | suppler_id   | price     |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
| ABC1          | 1            | 123       |
| ABC           | 2            | 222       |
| AB            | 3            | 234       |
| A             | 4            | 010       |
+---------------+--------------+-----------+
```

we then need to sort the result by price in ascending order and concat the supplier ID's to give a supplier order

```
+------------+----------------+
| code       | suppler_order  |
+------------+----------------+
| ABC123456  | 4,1,2,3        |
| ABC155555  | 4,1,2,3        |
| ...        | ...            |
+------------+----------------+
```

I hope that makes it clearer, thanks r

Comment: You want to get the row with the longest `destination_prefix` for each `supplier_id`?

Comment: Hi Barmar, that code is working but yes, for each supplier I need to look through the prices table to get the longest code match, repeat this for each supplier, so if 10 suppliers I will end up with 10 rows, 1 for each supplier all with there individual longest code matches. destination_prefix should have been code_prefix - sorry updated!

Comment: The join with supplier doesn't change. You get the row with the longest destination prefix grouped by `supplier_id` in the subquery.

Comment: how would I do a group by supplier_id with limit 1 per supplier_id ??

Comment: See the answers in the linked question.

Comment: Where they use `MAX(columnname)` you want to use `MAX(LENGTH(code_prefix))`

Comment: I can do group by MAX() type queries, however this is not giving the right results
```
Select  id, description, carrier_id, MAX(LENGTH(code_prefix)) 

from rates where 'ABC49160000000' like CONCAT(code_prefix , '%') 

group by supplier_id
```
is not returning the right match per supplier, it is seeming random from within the where result, not the best match

Comment: `SELECT r.* from rates AS r join (select supplier_id, MAX(LENGTH(code_prefix)) AS maxlength from rates group by supplier_id) AS r1 ON r.supplier_id = r1.supplier_id AND LENGTH(r.code_prefix) = r2.maxlength`

Comment: Hi Barmar, I have tried your code and have the same issue that I am getting 1 result per supplier however it it not the best match it just seems to be a random result from the set?
any ideas

Comment: Update your question with the full query, sample data, and the desired result. I'll reopen and then we can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it is clearer now. thx

Comment: Can't the `UNION DISTINCT` be eliminating by using `supplier_id IN (1,2,3)`?

Comment: Hi Rick, would that not then prevent the LIMIT 1 from getting the best match PER supplier to just be the best match across ALL suppliers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First define a view to get all the rows that match each code prefix for each supplier (if you had a newer MariaDB version you could use a CTE).

```
CREATE VIEW supplier_codes AS
SELECT DISTINCT c.code, p.code_prefix AS code_prefix, p.supplier_id, p.price
FROM codes AS c
JOIN prices AS p ON c.code LIKE CONCAT(p.code_prefix, '%');
```

You can then use a common idiom for getting the row with the max length of code prefix for each supplier ID.

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM supplier_codes AS t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT supplier_id, MAX(LENGTH(code_prefix)) AS maxlength
    FROM supplier_codes
    GROUP BY supplier_id
  ) AS t2 ON t1.supplier_id = t2.supplier_id AND LENGTH(t1.code_prefix) = t2.maxlength
```

Then you can join that with the `codes` table to get the grouped results for each code.

```
SELECT c.code, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sc.supplier_id ORDER BY sc.price) AS supplier_order
FROM codes AS c
JOIN (
  SELECT t1.*
  FROM supplier_codes AS t1
  JOIN (
    SELECT supplier_id, MAX(LENGTH(code_prefix)) AS maxlength
    FROM supplier_codes
    GROUP BY supplier_id, code
  ) AS t2 ON t1.supplier_id = t2.supplier_id AND LENGTH(t1.code_prefix) = t2.maxlength
) AS sc ON c.code = sc.code
GROUP BY c.code;
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b1b5f/12)

Comment: Thanks Barnar, so nearly their I think, the results for the second query are not quite right
SELECT t1.*
  FROM supplier_codes AS t1

using your fiddle data

ABC7777777 should match  ABC supplier 2

Comment: I was struggling to understand how it would work but have just noticed in the second query you show GROUP BY supplier_id, but final you include the GROUP BY supplier_id, code. I will give another go thx

Comment: I made 1 change - "AS t2 ON t1.supplier_id = t2.supplier_id AND LENGTH(t1.code_prefix) = t2.maxlength AND t1.code_prefix = t2.code_prefix to ensure it returned the longest match for the code, really happy thanks you so much Barmar